# htaccess downloading file instead of loading

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I would really like my index.html to be able to have a PHP script work on it. I read that you can do this through the htaccess file. I only have access to a subdomain website directory, where I can upload my files through FTP.

The directory did not have a htaccess file, so I created one using notepad: .htaccess and added this to the file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

The problem is, instead of loading the index.html page, it downloads it as a file...would I need to add something extra to the htaccess file? :S

Comment: Why don't just use an index.php?

Comment: I could...but I'd like to have a html extension lol

Comment: I guess I was concerned with seo, but i've been reading more into it and it doesn't seem to really matter what extension you have. I also have a few people already linking to the index.html page and don't want them ending up at a dead link

Comment: @Jess you could make your existing index.html page into a redirect to your index.php.  That would keep their existing links working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to name the file `index.html` to have it served by default. You can change the default document using your with an entry in your `.htaccess` file like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Then when you navigate to http://yoursubdomain.example.com you will be served `index.php` instead of `index.html`.

---

If really do want PHP to interpret your .html documents then the entry you had in your question will work when PHP is running as an Apache module.  If your host is running PHP as CGI, you want:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

If it still doesn't work, then this web page has some more suggestions:

- http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/how-to-parse-html-files-as-php/

Comment: I couldn't get the html to php working in the end :/ but the Directoryindex you suggested works fine! Thanks heaps :)

Comment: Thank you, that helped! 1and1 suddenly changed apache to 2.4 and it started to download index.php file instead of opening it, 1and1 were useless as usual...

Answer (score 2):

The directive you have sets the content-type of files with a .html file extension.

If the server has PHP installed and enabled, that content-type will cause it to be run though the PHP engine and then the output from that sent to the client.

If it doesn't have PHP installed, then the file will just be served up to the client with that content-type. Since browsers don't handle PHP scripts themselves, they will then just save the file.

You need to install and enable PHP as well as setting the content-type.

Answer (score -1):

Presumably your hosting is supporting PHP?

If so, then you need to rename your file from index.html to index.php

Comment: ok i see. if answer for first question is "yes", then have a look at this link - http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/php-in-html-files.html