# Resetting .htaccess in a particular directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This question is directly related to a previous question of mine :

[php files are downloaded instead of ran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992355/php-files-are-downloaded-instead-of-ran)

But I have narrowed down the problem so that answering one question technically answers both.

I have made many changes to .htaccess in a certain directory above the root. We'll just call it /dir. Somewhere along the way, I made a change that broke the way php runs files. My overall goal is to get php to run .php files again; however my question is about resetting the .htaccess for /dir. I created php files in the directory before /dir (previous/dir) and they run fine, so I just need to reset whatever changes are being held onto for that directory.

How can I clear all .htaccess for that directory.

Keep in mind, I have cleared the .htaccess file already. Whatever changes happened are being stored somewhere in apache that I can't get to. I just want to reset them and go back to where php was working in that directory.

Thanks.

Comment: `php_flag engine 1` ?

Comment: Again, like on the last question.  You need to provide appropriate configuration sections that you were editing in various .htaccess file and Apache host config files. Without that the only advice you are going to get is to check your configurations in these files.

Comment: @MikeBrant Sorry, I guess I just don't understand what you're asking. I either don't have access or don't know where to look for the host config files. Everything I changed was at the directory level. I just want to reset that directory.

Comment: Then show the .htaccess files for that directory and all .htaccess file in directories above it (which may also have an effect).

Comment: @MikeBrant thats what I tried to tell you. They're all empty. Even in the root.

Comment: @SmashCode Well what were they before? You probably removed something like `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` which would allow .html files to be parsed by PHP

Comment: @MikeBrant I changed it so many times, thats what I want to reset it. I've had about 25 different combinations of AddType application/x-httpd-php .html, AddType application/x-http-php5 .html, AddHander x-http-php5 .html, AddType application/x-http-php5 .html .htm .php. .php5, etc. I was trying to find the right combination and I broke something that I have no record of.

Comment: @SmashCode Well we learned a lesson about source control now didn't we? Hard to give much advice in that case without knowing specifics about your Apache configuration.

Comment: @SmashCode I guess "reset" is a relative term.  If you have removed .htaccess altogether from all your web directories, I would consider that "reset".  If by "reset" you mean go back to what you had in your .htaccess file before, I don't believe we can provide any help, as we have no idea what was in there before.

Comment: @MikeBrant I'm asking about resetting .htaccess for a particular directory. I'm no longer interested in what broke it. All I know is that my Apache configuration everywhere but that directory works so I just want to reset that directory.

Comment: @MikeBrant Sorry, I should've made that clear, by reset, I mean back to where it was before I even touched it. Something I changed is being stored even after the .htaccess has been deleted.

Comment: @MikeBrant Starting with a blank .htaccess, what would be the standard AddType/AddHandler/SetHandler to just get basic php working? Or would you need info for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the original .htaccess had changed permissions to the directory because of password protecting. After I deleted the .htaccess file and the pwd, the permissions were still altered. After fixing the permissions I was easily able to fix everything.